# SQL server command line: abort instead of GO

Tags: sql-server

I am in SQL server command line utility (sqlcmd.exe) and I type:

```
1> UPDATE usercache SET TargetUri = NULL WHERE name='Alexander';
2> GO
(5 rows affected)
```

But consider the case where I forgot the `WHERE` statement:

```
1> UPDATE usercache SET TargetUri = NULL;
2>
```

How would I now abort the execution? As of now, I am using Ctrl+C and then reconnect to the server, but is there a SQL statement that could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a SQL statement that could help me?

No, there isn't. But there is an SQLCMD command that can: `RESET`, in much the same way that you usually use `GO` to send any statements.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx):

> **RESET**
>   Clears the statement cache.

And:

> **GO** [count]
>   GO signals both the end of a batch and the execution of any cached Transact-SQL statements.

You'll also observe, after issuing `RESET`, that the line number reverts to `1>`.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to always use `BEGIN TRAN` with "risky" queries, like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE usercache SET TargetUri = NULL;
```

After you are sure that this is actually the query that you want to run on your server, you issue a `COMMIT` command to save changes to the DB.

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE usercache SET TargetUri = NULL;

COMMIT
```

If you want to undo the changes made by this query, all you have to do is issue a `ROLLBACK` command instead of `COMMIT` and you're safely back where you started.

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE usercache SET TargetUri = NULL;

ROLLBACK
```